# My Recycler View Search Filter is not working for list of objects

Tags: java, android, firebase, search, android-recyclerview

I have tried a lot but my search filter is not working with array of objects and no errors shown.
When the search query is typed all list gets cleared and not working at all or showing query related data in search filter.

Here is the RecyclerViewAdapter.java file:

```
package com.example.myapplication.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.myapplication.R;
import com.example.myapplication.model.Contacts;


import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable
{
    private Context context;
    List<Contacts> contactsList;

    List<Contacts> filterList;
    List<Contacts> filteredList;




    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Contacts> contactsList)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.contactsList = contactsList;
        filterList = this.contactsList;

        Log.d("dbneer","i m");
    }






    // where to get the single card as viewholder object (DISPLAY FORMAT OF A SINGLE CARD ? OR CREATING A SKELETON DESIGN OF SINGLE CARD)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);


    }


    // what will happen after we create the viewholder object  I.E.  PUTTING VALUES OF SINGLE CARD INTO SKELETON DESIGN OF SINGLE CARD
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Contacts contact = contactsList.get(position);

        holder.contactName.setText(contact.getName());
        holder.phoneNumber.setText(contact.getPhoneNumber());
    }


    // how many items?
    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return contactsList.size();
    }



    // search bar implementation

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        return new Filter()
        {
            // run on background thread
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                //Log.d("dbneer", "i am here");

                if (charSequence.toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    filteredList = filterList;
                }
                else {
                    for (Contacts con : filterList) {
                       // Log.d("dbneer", "hiii" + con.getName() + charSequence.toString().toLowerCase());

                        if (con.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                            filteredList.add(con);
                        }

                    }

                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

                filterResults.values = filteredList;


                return filterResults;
            }

            // run on ui thread
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults)
            {
                if (filterResults != null && filterResults.values != null)
                {
                    contactsList.clear();
                    contactsList.addAll((Collection<? extends Contacts>) filterResults.values);

                    /*
                    for(Contacts c : contactsList)
                    {
                        String h = c.getName();

                        Log.d("dbneer", "working" + h);
                    }
                    */

                }
                else {
                    Log.d("dbneer", "not working");
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    // creation of viewholder object:
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        public TextView contactName;
        public TextView phoneNumber;
        public ImageView iconButton;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            contactName  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            phoneNumber  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
            iconButton  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            iconButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            // Log.d("viewholder", "Clicked");

            int position = this.getAdapterPosition();
            Contacts contact = contactsList.get(position);
            String name = contact.getName();
            String phone = contact.getPhoneNumber();

            Toast.makeText(context, "The position is" + String.valueOf(position) + "Name is"
                    + name + " Phone is " + phone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Intent intent = new Intent(context, com.example.myapplication.displayContact.class);
            intent.putExtra("Rname", name);
            intent.putExtra("Rphone", phone);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity3.java:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import android.widget.Toast;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;



import com.example.myapplication.adapter.RecyclerViewAdapter;

// MySqlLite mydbhandler libraries:

import com.example.myapplication.data.MyDbHandler;
import com.example.myapplication.model.Contacts;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

//firebase database libraries:

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity
{
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

        ArrayList<Contacts> contactsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        //List<Contacts> contactsList;

        private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
        private DatabaseReference reff;







    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);



            //Recyclerview initialization
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



            /*
            // creating mydbhandler class object:

            MyDbHandler db = new MyDbHandler(Activity3.this);

            //deleting all rows:
            //db.deleteAll();

            // creating contact object:
            Contacts teer = new Contacts();
            teer.setPhoneNumber("9999900000");
            teer.setName("Neer");
            teer.setState("Haryana");
            db.addContact(teer);







            // get all contacts


            contactsList = db.getAllContacts();


            for(Contacts contact : contactsList)
            {

                Log.d("dbneer","Id: " + contact.getId() + "\n"
                        + "Name: " + contact.getName() + "\n" +
                        "Phone Number: " + contact.getPhoneNumber() + "\n" + "State:" + contact.getState());



                contactsArrayList.add(contact);
            }

            */



            //using firebase database handing:

            // contact = new Contacts();



        try
        {
            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            reff = firebaseDatabase.getReferenceFromUrl("https://myapplication-6539a.firebaseio.com/").child("shivam");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("dberror","database error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    // get all children objects at this level

                    Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

                    // shake hands with each of the child

                    for(DataSnapshot child : children)
                    {
                        Contacts contact = child.getValue(Contacts.class);

                        // firebase testing :
                        Log.d("dbneer","id is "+contact.getId());
                        Log.d("dbneer","name is "+contact.getName());
                        Log.d("dbneer","phone number is "+contact.getPhoneNumber());
                        Log.d("dbneer","state is "+contact.getState());

                        contactsArrayList.add(contact);
                    }

                    // Use your recyclerview
                    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(Activity3.this, contactsArrayList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

                    // Finally, you have nailed it bro!! did your realtime database operation...!
                    Log.d("dbneer","reached in recycler view area");


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

    }

    //menu bar search fuctionality:

        @Override

        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            SearchView searchview = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
            searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
                {
                    recyclerViewAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
                {
                    recyclerViewAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    return false;
                }
            });

            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        }



}
```

Contacts.java:

```
package com.example.myapplication.model;

// change long datatype of phonenumber into string while dealing with sql-lite and viceversa for firebase:

public class Contacts
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String state;

    public Contacts(String name, String phoneNumber, String state)
    {

        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Contacts(int id, String name, String phoneNumber, String state)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Contacts()
    {
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber)
    {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getState()
    {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state)
    {
        this.state = state;
    }

}
```

Nothing shows up on running code in search filter as all list objects vanishes and never returned even after returning back from search filter.

Comment: you did not manipulate the data from filter function. maybe you can pass it on recyclerview adapter.

Comment: i think it would help to add how your data is structured (a screenshot) and what you want to search in it, so that someone can provide you a query ,and yes you don't need a filtered list and unfiltered thing you can directly query the firebase database just by typing it is the searchview this is what i do in my app, and for better querying capabilities you can consider using firestore

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find an article that can help you [filter results](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444).